# Home wifi network with 3 routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I have a 3 floor house and i want to make a wifi network to cover all of it.
The internet provider gives me the fiber connection on the middle floor
I want to buy 2 extra routers (D-Link WiFi Router AX 1500 Wi-Fi 6 Router) for the upper and lower floor that i can connect them with the middle floor provider router through LAN connection (i have cat5 cabling all over the house).
Which is the best way to set up the extra 2 routers ?? To use them as access points or something different ?? how can i have the same wifi name/connection in all 3 floors so i wont have to change wifi networks from one floor to the other ???

Thanks in advance for your advices

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this. I set up routers on the same subnet.  LAN to LAN, Static IP for routers on main network, DHCP OFF on added routers. Only one DHCP server.

Comment: Why routers and not just WiFi repeaters? Are you segregating traffic for performance/security reasons?

Comment: If you didn't buy the routes yet, have you thought about a mesh Wi-Fi solution?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick repeaters can be convenient when there are serious limitations to your area, but you lose a LOT of bandwidth and speed with each wireless hop. A network that supports roaming, with each router having their wired network connection, is best.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have Ethernet cabling throughout your house, you just need two more APs. An AP is any device that publishes a Wi-Fi network and transparently forwards (bridges) traffic between wireless clients and wired devices on the Ethernet LAN. They're simply "points of access" where wireless clients can get access to the Ethernet LAN.

Because you already have a home gateway router on your home Ethernet LAN, and that router already provides NAT and DHCP service, you don't need your additional devices to do anything but transparently forward traffic. You don't need them to be routers or DHCP servers.

Please note that just about anything that can publish a Wi-Fi network, and has an Ethernet port, can be configured to act as a simple AP. That includes not only products with "AP" (Access Point) in the name, but also many things sold as wireless routers, repeaters, or extenders. Sometimes knowing this can allow you to save money, because the devices that actually have "AP" in the name are often targeted towards business users and carry a higher price tag.

You don't need a mesh system *per se*. "Mesh" is shorthand for "wireless mesh topology", which is where the APs form a multi-way mesh of wireless interconnections amongst themselves. So mesh is what you need when you do NOT have Ethernet cabling available for the backhauls from the APs to the main NAT gateway router at the head of your network.

On the other hand, most mesh systems can be configured to turn off the wireless mesh backhauls and use Ethernet backhauls instead, which means they're just a set of APs that can be conveniently configured as a unified fleet from a smartphone app. That way they can coordinate their own channel choices amongst themselves, and if you want to make a network-wide configuration change, you can do it once through the app instead of having to make the change on each AP one at a time.

If you go with two additional APs that are NOT a part of a unified system, all you have to do is set them all to publish the same network name[s] (SSID[s]) with the same wireless security type and wireless network password, and your clients should automatically, seamlessly roam between them. Wi-Fi leaves the roaming decisions completely up to the clients, so roaming works even between APs from different brands that know nothing about each other; there's no inter-AP coordination required. There are some thing APs can do to help keep clients well-informed so that the clients can make better roaming decisions, but it's not required. Non-buggy clients will roam even without any hints or helps from the network.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

As @Dr_Xunil said, the best solution is mesh Wi-Fi, which I have in my 3 floor house where the ISP input and my router is in the basement and I have Cat6 cabling going to 1st floor and 2nd floor rooms.

I use the tp-link [Deco M9 Plus](https://www.tp-link.com/ca/home-networking/deco/deco-m9-plus/) (Amazon link [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N1NZ99R)) which has dedicated Wifi backhaul channel, which I actually don't use since I connect those each unit with Cat 6 cables.

So if you're going to hook those Wifi mesh units with Cat 6 cables, you can do with a less expensive tp-link [Deco M5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079PXYLZW).

Comment: Thanks for your reply